# How to add a button under an image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have googled about this problem but all i could find is how to add an image to a button. This is the opposite of my question kinda.

I have tried to use the image as a frame but did not work.

I have an image in mainwindow and i would like to add a button under the image. When i apply this the image disappears and i see only a little button somewhere on the screen. I add the button in the header method and below i share the picture with button and without button. Please ignore ugliness of the images.

```
class MainMenu():
    def __init__(self,root,UserName):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("800x500")
        self.root.configure(background = "grey")

        self.Body()

        self.Header(UserName)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def Body(self):

        MidImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("MyTkinter/Animasyon Çember/don1.png").resize((450,300)))
        #MidImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("MyTkinter/images/aot1.jpg").resize((450,300)))

        
        labelImg = Label(self.root,image = MidImg)
        labelImg.image = MidImg
        #labelImg.pack(side = "top",fill = "both", expand = "yes")
        labelImg.grid(columnspan = 2,sticky = "N",padx = 180)

        but= Button(labelImg, text = "Para Ekle")
        but.grid(sticky = "SE")
```

Without button

[image: Without button]

With button

[image: With button]

Comment: When using `.grid` why aren't you passing in `row` and `column`?

Comment: Well i have passed it but result was same.

Comment: Also you know that the master for your button is the image?

Comment: change `Button(labelImg, text="Para Ekle")` to `Button(self.root, text="Para Ekle")`

Comment: I thought i could use the "labelImg" as a master.

Comment: Yes but my guess is that the button tells the label to shrink and also goes above the image

Comment: `Button(labelImg, text="Para Ekle") to Button(self.root, text="Para Ekle")`  this worked but now the button is on the image not below.

Comment: ok thank you i have solved it. `add_money.grid(sticky = "SE",row = 1, column = 0)` i passed in  the row = 1 and it worked as i wanted thanks!!